# Logs on Event Hub per partition

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I'm using event hub for event processing in Azure and I have two event hubs under the same Event Hub namespace and both of them have different count of partitions. I'm quite new in using Azure Portal and couldn't figure out the logs and metrics to show count of requests that were processed through each partition. Can someone point me to where to look at and what to use to display a chart of some sort showing the number of requests that were processed through each partition?

Comment: If you are looking for partition level volume then you are probably running on some architectural problem. Why do you need to that metric?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can someone point me to where to look at and what to use to display a
> chart of some sort showing the number of requests that were processed
> through each partition?

For metrics, there is no way to show the number of requests that processed through each partition.

This is all of the metrics that was been supported:

[Microsoft.EventHub/clusters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/metrics-supported#microsofteventhubclusters)

[Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/metrics-supported#microsofteventhubnamespaces)